# Where to download Blender's complete package?

Tags: installation

Where do I go to download the whole install package, e.g., blender-2.80-50ccbe6bb233-win64?

I assume Blender will update again, and I do NOT connect my workstation to the internet at all, nor my powerline directly.

Answer (score 2):

Every [download of Blender](https://www.blender.org/download/) is complete and works offline, not matter if it's the installer or archive version. Also Blender doesn't auto-update, updates need to be installed manually.

If you're looking for a build from a specific commit (hash), you'll have to [build Blender](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender) yourself. Once you've cloned the git repository you can revert to the commit hash you want to build.